# Email Notification when Calendar Event is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm updating some calendar events with this part of my script:

```
// Update the event's start and end times with the new date
          event.setTime(newStartTime, newEndTime);

          // Notify guests about the change
          var eventOptions = {
            sendUpdates: "all" // Send updates to all guests
          };

          event.setGuestsCanModify(false); // Optional: Prevent guests from modifying the event

          event.updateEvent(eventOptions); // Update the event with notification
```

People in my guestlist don't usually use google calendar, so I need to make sure they receive an email about the change of the event. Otherwise, their calendars will be outdated with events that are no longer taking place at the same time.

I had no problem with sending notifications when the event was initially created.

When I make the adjustment manually in my google calendar, notifications are sent successfully...

I see the option to delete the event & create a new one, but this would leave the participant's calendars with loads of visible deleted events...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Edit: I tried to delete and re-add the guests to the event, hoping this would trigger the notification, but it didnt:

`// Get the list of guests
var guests = event.getGuestList();

// Remove all guests from the event
for (var i = 0; i < guests.length; i++) {
  event.removeGuest(guests[i].getEmail());
}

// Re-add guests to the event
for (var i = 0; i < guests.length; i++) {
  event.addGuest(guests[i].getEmail());
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function createEventUpdateTrigger(handler = "captureTheUpdateEventObject") {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == handler).filter(e => e).length ==0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(handler).forUserCalendar("calendarId").onEventUpdated().create();
  }
}
function captureTheUpdateEventObject(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendarId);
  //Put the rest of your code here.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
I'm not sure if I can follow (I'm not very well experienced with Apps Script).
Could this be included in a pre-existing on-edit trigger function? The code sample I provided belongs to an onEdit trigger, which automatically updates start and end time of the event).